# Seleccionar valor más alto de cada dia en SQL

Tags: php, sql

Estoy tratando de mostrar una tabla llamada "Historial", para ponerlos en contexto esta tabla esta recibiendo datos de un sensor de temperatura, por lo cual la tabla es extensa, quiero recuperar solo la temperatura más alta de cada dia. 
[image: Datos]

[image: Estructura de la tabla]

Por ejemplo 29.80 del dia 07 y 29.70 del dia 08, no son  solo dos dias, como les comente es una tabla que se actualiza constantemente con nuevos dias.

Comment: Hola Osvaldo, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles, y en caso de haberlo sido marcar como aceptada la que mas te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente (en SQL SERVER):

```sql
select columna1 AS 'Columna', 
       max(temp) AS 'Temperatura',
       cast(dia as date) AS 'Dia',
from ( 
  values('cerda1', 23.6, '2022-09-10 15:00:32'), 
        ('cerda1', 28.6, '2022-09-10 16:00:32'), 
        ('cerda1', 22.6, '2022-09-11 15:00:32'),
        ('cerda1', 19.6, '2022-09-11 18:10:32')
  ) x (columna1,temp,dia)
group by columna1, cast(dia as date)
```

Comment: He añadido la estructura de la tabla :)

Answer (score 0):

Haz un agrupamiento por la fecha:

Nota: el campo `temperatura` debería ser tipo `decimal` de acuerdo a los valores que guardas, no `varchar`.

```
SELECT MAX(h.temperatura), h.fechayhora FROM Historial h GROUP BY h.fechayhora ORDER BY h.fechayhora DESC;
```

Comment: Tu respuesta no es correcta, no estas agrupando por la fecha, sino que estas teniendo en cuenta tambien las horas, del campo datetime solo debes tener en cuenta la parte de la fecha y descartar la parte de las horas, investiga sobre la funcion cast

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast([fechayhora] as date) as Fecha, max(temperatura) as "Temperatura máxima", 
from tabla
group by cast([fechayhora] as date)
```

En esta consulta usas la **función cast** para obtener de un **campo DateTime** solo la parte que representa a la fecha, descartando las horas, usas la **claúsula group by** agrupando precisamente por la parte de la fecha y en la **claúsula select** muestras la parte de la fecha y usas la **función de agregación max** sobre el **campo temperatura** obteniendo de esta forma la máxima temperatura de un día.